# Mention user in heroCard botframework (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, typescript, microsoft-teams, botframework

The user wants to return a message to a teams channel. In the card, I would like to mention the user that sent the message back to the channel. Following the instructions [on the Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/channel-and-group-conversations?tabs=typescript) did not work. Using that TextEncoder, the user's name would get encoded and just sent back as numbers (eg. 82,111,115,105,101,114,115,44,32,74,97,115,112,10,....).

The way it is set up below returns the user's name, but not as a mention, just the text. How do I turn this into code that actually mentions the user?

I also tried using `context.activity.from.name` in the heroCard, but that didn't mention the user either.

```
const mention = {
            mentioned: context.activity.from,
            text: `<at>${context.activity.from.name}</at>`,
            type: 'mention'
        } as Mention;

        const heroCard = CardFactory.heroCard(
            `Returned question by ${ mention.mentioned.name }`,
            `${ mention.mentioned.name } You can internally discuss the user request below. ` +
            'Once ready, one person can take ownership of the conversation with the user by pressing the button. ' +
            'The user\'s question: ' + teamsSupport.question,
            null,
            CardFactory.actions([
                {
                    title: 'Takeover conversation',
                    type: ActionTypes.MessageBack,
                    displayText: `I will take this conversation.`,
                    text: this.configService.get<string>('TakeoverConfirmation') + teamsSupport.sessionId,
                    value: ''
                },
                {
                    title: 'Show chat history',
                    type: ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
                    value: 'https://****/conversations/' + teamsSupport.sessionId
                }
            ])
        );

        const suggestedActions = MessageFactory.attachment(heroCard);
        suggestedActions.entities = [mention];
```

Comment: I can see that TextEncoder.encode does indeed seem to return a byte array instead of a string. They probably meant for you to XML-encode the string like C# does. Anyway, I have two questions. 1. Is the problem just that the text of the name gets displayed incorrectly or is the link not working in addition to getting displayed incorrectly? 2. Are you able to get mentions to work correctly outside of a hero card, i.e. in the message text?

Comment: When using the TextEncoder, I just get the byte array so that's displayed incorrectly. When not using that encoder, I do get the correct name. In both cases, there is no link. 

I haven't tried doing it in message text yet, I will try that tomorrow and answer again when I have.

Comment: Mention is supported only in [Text Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/channel-and-group-conversations?tabs=typescript#adding-mentions-to-your-messages) and [Adaptive Card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#mention-support-within-adaptive-cards-v12).

Comment: I thought it was available in herocards too, Text message mentions do work now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Wajeed-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576503/wajeed-msft) correctly stated, Mentions are not supported in heroCards.

They are however supported for [Text Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#mention-support-within-adaptive-cards-v12) and [Adaptive cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/channel-and-group-conversations?tabs=typescript#adding-mentions-to-your-messages) and this works for me.